# matplotlib.pyplot does not work in my anaconda environment

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, anaconda

I am using Windows 10, and I'm on an anaconda environment with python 3.6. Matplotlib.pyplot doesn't work for some reason. Once I write `plt.show()`, the program stalls. Matplotlib is installed and updated in my anaconda environment.

For instance, this program didn't work when I wrote this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
x = t ** 2
plt.plot(t, x)
plt.show()
```

Furthermore, matplotlib.pyplot does in fact work outside anaconda. Any ideas?

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Comment: plt.show() results in the program stalling. For example, I set t to be a np array of integers between 0 and 10, and x is every element of t squared. I wrote plt.plot(t, x) then plt.show() and the program stalled.

Comment: stalled? You don't see any plot?